# how do i detect a spacebar in a getline/cin and not ignore it or split it into two inputs?

Tags: c++

lets say im making a getline. like I want to getline (cin, employeecode), and when the user
enters the employee code and they typed something like, A 05,  I want to detect the spacebar in the center and then give an appropriate error message, how would I tackle something like that, I do not want to just just normal cin as that makes it into two input ( A as 1st input, 05 as 2nd input )and if I use cin.ignore() I cant detect the space bar as it ignores the space bar. I tried something with the ASCII value of spacebar, which is 32, so when it detects the the value of 32 it will do something but I dont know how to implement that either.

Comment: "I tried something" - please show what you have tried and how it failed (compiler error/invalid results/etc)

Comment: i just read it on some stack overflow but i didnt know how to implement it at all so sorry.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read upto spacebar(that is a space) then you can use:

```
std::getline(std::cin, line, ' ');
```

The above will stop when a space is read. You can try out the program [here](https://onlinegdb.com/NgAGlG6y7).

So lets say you have the program:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    std::string line;
  std::getline(std::cin, line, ' ');
std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
}
```

Then if the user enters the string `Anoop Rana` then only the first name `Anoop` is read into the variable `line` and everything after the space is not read into the variable line.

**Edit**
If you want to check whether the input given by the user has a space and then print out some message like `invalid input` if it has a space, you can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   
string name;
getline(cin, name);
if(name.find(' ')!= string::npos)//check whether the input has a space or not
{
    cout<<"Invalid input"<<endl;
}
else 
{
    cout<<"Input Is Correct"<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Erm, basically doing a code where if i type employee code, cin>> employeecode, 
and in the cin employeecode, lets say i type  A 05, i want to make it detect the space bar, then cout >> invalid input (no whitespace allowed), so the variable is not registered at all and not just ignore the things after the space bar.

Comment: @YongS Ok then you can take the input from user and then check using `find()` method if the input contains a space or not as i did in my **edited** answer. Check it out. At the end of my answer i have checked whether the input entered by the user has a space or not and depending on that printed a suitable message.

Comment: the way my teacher is teaching me ,i do not use std;; and im using using namespace std; at the start, how would i tackle it then?

Comment: @YongS I have removed all the `std` and used `using namespace std;` in my edited answer now. Check out the latest update to my answer. It's just like your teacher taught you.

Comment: What if its a int variable though, how would we tackle that. like my code has one part where i validate the day someone entered has to from day 1 to 31. 
cout << "Please Enter the day: ";
    cin >> employees[numberOfExistingEmployees].day;
if(employees[numberOfExistingEmployees].day >= 1 && employees[numberOfExistingEmployees].day <= 31){
     validationForDay = true;
how would i make it so that when i cin " 2 2 " it gives a validation without splitting into two inputs.

Comment: @YongS In your comment did you write "22" or "2 2" ? If you want to convert the input entered by the user into an `int` then you can do that as well. Can you explain in a little more detail what exact situation you have so that i can tell you exactly how to solve it. Also, you can email me your entire explanation of the thing that you have in mind(in as much detail as you can) @`ranaanoop986@gmail.com` . Or you can edit your question here and i will read it from here.